# Cloudlinux + CageFS + PHP Selector - how to update default php.ini for each PHP version or for each domain account?

Tags: php, cpanel, whm, centos

My server runs Cloudlinux 5.11 with CageFS and PHP Selector. Default PHP version is 5.3.

I have one account using PHP 5.3, one account using PHP 5.5, and one account using PHP 5.6.

I'm trying to figure out how to update each account's php.ini or each PHP version's default php.ini.

So far I've figured out how to update PHP 5.3's default php.ini:

1. `phpinfo` on the PHP 5.3 account shows the loaded configuration file is from `/usr/selector.etc/php.ini`.
2. Update /usr/local/lib/php.ini
3. Run `cagefsctl --force-update`
4. Rebuild Apache

Then the modified `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` is reflected on the `phpinfo`.

However, for PHP 5.5. and 5.6 accounts, I can't figure out how to update their default php.ini's.

1. Their `phpinfo` shows the loaded configuration files are from `/opt/alt/php55/etc/php.ini` and `/opt/alt/php56/etc/php.ini`
2. Update those files
3. Run `cagefsctl --force-update`
4. Rebuild Apache

Afterwards, the changes of these php.ini's are reverted! So where is the right place to change these PHP versions' default php.ini's?

Being able to update each PHP version's default php.ini would work for me, but it would be even easier and more flexible if each domain account (or even each folder) can have its own php.ini.

I've tried `/public_html/php.ini` and `/public_html/.htaccess`. They don't take effect at all. `ini_set` in script works though, but of course I don't want to reply on just `ini_set`.

Comment: Are the ini files, or the folder they're in, symbolic links?

Comment: All the files I mentioned here are not symbolic links. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. For alternative PHP versions, the process is different.

After modifying `/opt/alt/phpXX/etc/php.ini`

Run `cagefsctl --rebuild-alt-php-ini`

That's it. No need to rebuild apache.

For an individual user's php.ini, check [here](http://docs.cloudlinux.com/index.html?individual_php_ini_files.html)